# Storing data in a specific format using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In one of my tables,I have an attribute that i want to store in a specific format like this
`NV[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]. Ex: NV0001`.
Can anyone help me?
P/s: sorry for the bad english :P

Comment: Would you have to format garbage like `12318.123NV' to fit this specific format you desire or are you wanting the database to reject the insert/update if it doesn't fit the format?

Comment: Well, i want the database to reject values that doesn't fit the format.

Comment: Read this:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm  Specifically, this:  •A check constraint requires a value in the database to comply with a specified condition.

Comment: sorry, i still have no clues on how to do this :(( i need helps.